# AS3: Total count of merged similar sub arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, actionscript, nested

I've got what should be a simple problem I can't quiet get my head around:

Say I have these array values (could change, but same basic structure):

```
TempArray[0]: 0,0
TempArray[1]: 0,0,0,0
TempArray[2]: 0,0,0,0
TempArray[3]: 3,3,3,4
TempArray[4]: 4,4
TempArray[5]: 4,3,4,4
TempArray[6]: 6,6
```

The sub array could go deeper, or it could be less, but it's always a matter of comparing within the subarray to get the goal.

The answer I'm after is a count of total matched groups. So since there is a 4 and 3 together all 4 and 3s would simply count as a 1.

My expected result from the above would be 3 (a count of total unique groups). All the 0s are 1, all the 3 and 4s merge together to be 2 and the 6 are 3. I just care the value is 3.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

For instance, if you're only dealing with integers

-1/ Check your first Array

-2/ [sort](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort%28%29) it

-3/ [slice](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#slice%28%29) any element that already exist until you have an Array of unique elements.
      you've created your first group

-4/ with the remaining Arrays, compare to your existing groups and slice any element that are already contained in a previous group. With your example Temp[3] would end up as group [3, 4]

-5 count your groups